# Saving MP3 playlist to file

Tags: java, io, jlist

I am making my own crude MP3 player, and I now have a JList with which I have populated a number of files in the form of MP3 objects (displayed on frame using DefaultListModel).

I would now like to have the oppurtunity to save this JList to a file on disk. How would I go about doing this?

I'm very new with programming and Java, so help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to retrieve the data back in the form of the Jlist object itself you better use object serialization.

ObjectOutput ObjOut = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));

else if you want the data to be retrieved in the text format follow the steps mentioned by others.

might be tis code will help

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


  String filename = "playlist.dat";

   File f = new File(filename);

  try{

   ObjectOutput ObjOut = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));

     ObjOut.writeObject(//ur JList object);

     ObjOut.close();

     System.out.println("Serializing an Object Creation completed successfully.");

    }

catch(IOException e){

   System.out.println(e.getMessage());

      }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is by using [Serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/).

The more consistent (i think this is the word) is using the [java io](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/) to write the list to the file, item by item, using a simple **for** loop.

Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either [M3U](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) or [PLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLS_(file_format)) format to create a playlist files from the items in your JList.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to save this as a playlist file, to be opened with a media player?

If you're just trying to save this as like a text file, open a simple output stream and call it 'playlist.txt', and just loop through each record of the JList and write the info you need followed by a new line (\n).